# Python Dataframes : Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. First one is like a parent df with many other features and second df contains only the unique values of `df['Col1']`. Please see below:

**df1**

```
Col1
----
C1
C1
C1
C2
C2
C2
```

**df2**

```
Col1  Col2
----  ----
C1    S1
C2    S2
```

What would be a clean way to combine df2 to df1 as below ?
**df1**

```
Col1    Col2
----    ----
C1      S1
C1      S1
C1      S1
C2      S2
C2      S2
C2      S2
```

Comment: Read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: `df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Col1')` or `df1['Col2'] = df1['Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2'])` both options have explanations in the [accepted answer of the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/15497888)